# How to allow for the Late Keyword?

Tags: flutter, animation, operator-keyword

I would like to make an animation similar to what is seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIcS70JcNa4&t=604s

However, my late keyword has an error as seen in:

[image: Showcase of late error in code]

How do I allow the late keyword?

My sdk envt is

environment:
sdk: ">=2.2.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: Change sdk version to this: “>=2.12.0 < 3.0.0”

Comment: bro, almost all the pages pop up errors when I changed the sdk to that. ><

Comment: you need to correct them as late was introduced with null-safety so there would errors, make sure you migrate everything.

Comment: As in, follow the complete directions at https://dart.dev/dart-2

Comment: Roger that, thanks guys!. Just curious, is there a way to create the same animation without going down this path of using late keyword?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code to this and the animation I want has appeared. Without the late keyword or changing sdk.

```
AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 3))
          ..repeat(reverse: true);
    _animation = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(0, -0.3))
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeInOut));
  }
```

Thanks all! Take care, stay safe!